# Warning: include(lang/1%00'=1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampplite\security\htdocs\index.php on line 12

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

Getting a really strange error here.  I'm developing a WordPress website locally via ServerPress (called localhost.dev).  Everything works fine except for the url localhost.dev/security.  I'm trying to give a page this URL, but when I do, the error below shows up on the page.  I've never encountered this before, does anyone have an idea how I can fix this?

> ( ! ) Warning: include(lang/1%00'=1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampplite\security\htdocs\index.php on line 12
>
> ( ! ) Warning: include(): Failed opening 'lang/1%00'=1.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampplite\php\PEAR') in C:\xampplite\security\htdocs\index.php on line 12

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C71Tc.jpg)

Comment: What's at `C:\xampplite\security\htdocs\index.php on line 12`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that someone had the same problem :

In file `lang.tmp` write only `en` set up english language and all will be correct.

https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?t=68507&p=242365

Comment: Thanks for finding this, it's gotten rid of the error message.  Now when I go to localhost.dev/security, it takes me to the XAMPP Security page.  Figures this will go away once I move this to my staging server online rather than locally with XAMPP/ServerPress.